# How to skip certain array indexes?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Need to sort only odd values in array, but even values must remain on their places.

Here is my code:

```
public static int[] sortArray(int[] array) {

    int length = array.length;
    int temp = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < length - i; j++) {
            if (j > 0 && array[j] % 2 == 0)continue;

                if (array[j - 1] > array[j]){
                    temp = array[j - 1];
                    array[j - 1] = array[j];
                    array[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

    return array;
}
```

input: `new int[]{5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4, 0}`

output: `[1, 3, 5, 2, 8, 4, 0]`

but I need: `[1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 4, 0]`

How to skip certain indexes in array?

Think this should be connected with `continue` operator, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You can't just swap `array[j]` with its immediate predecessor when the former is odd, because the latter may be even.  You need to find the nearest predecessor which is odd to see if an exchange is in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code instead:

```
public static int[] sortArray(int[] array) {

    int length = array.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
        int k = -1; // The index of last odd element
        for (int j = 0; j < length - i; j++)
            if (array[j] % 2 != 0) {
                if (k >= 0 && array[k] > array[j]) {
                    int temp = array[k];
                    array[k] = array[j];
                    array[j] = temp;
                }
                k = j;
            }
    }

    return array;
}
```

Comment: hint: returning the array is optional as external array will modified.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, this code is logically false.
Because if you switch number with this code,

```
temp = array[j - 1];
array[j - 1] = array[j];
array[j] = temp;
```

you can't keep place of even numbers.

how about just search odd numbers in array, and just sort odd numbers??

Comment: tnen I need to back sort nubrers on their places in array. Sort odd numbers is not a problem, problem is back it on their places in array, and not mix with even numbers. Even numbers should remain on their places

Comment: @IMBABOT That is not a problem. First, store the indices of the odd numbers in an array. Then, sort the odd numbers only. Then, put each odd number to the index given by the stored index array.

Answer (score 2):

for a simple algorithm like bubble sort, you can simply ignore the even values with `continue`

```
for(int i=0; i<ar.length; i++) {
    if(ar[i] % 2 == 0) continue;
    for(int j=i; j<ar.length; j++) {
        if(ar[j] % 2 == 0) continue;

        if(ar[i] > ar[j]) {
        int temp = ar[i];
        ar[i] = ar[j];
        ar[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: output for this: `[3, 1, 5, 2, 8, 4, 0]`, should `[1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 4, 0]`

Comment: Your statement - `but even values must remain on their places.` : 2 moved from 3rd index to 2nd index? (talking in terms array index), 8 moved from  4th to 3rd index.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun:

With Lamda and Stream ;-)

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class IntSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[]{5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4, 0};

        sortOnlyOddRemainEven(array);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }

    public static void sortOnlyOddRemainEven(int[] array) {

        // get list of sorted odd numbers
        int[] odd = Arrays.stream(array).filter( x -> x % 2 != 0).sorted().toArray();

        int c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if(array[i] % 2 != 0)
            {
                // replace each odd number in the array with the sorted one
                array[i] = odd[c++];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can replace the for loop with streams as well.

Comment: Do you mean map or a better solution? [Map is not a nice version](https://pastebin.com/MntMxaD5)

Comment: streams are not always better than a for loop.

Comment: See my answer please.

Comment: @KorayTugay: pop() is a nice idea ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution is to wrap the original array in a `OddArray` class, which makes the underlying original array appear to hold just the odd entries.  Something like:

```
class OddArray {

  int[] baseArray;

  // Constructor
  OddArray(int[] base) {
    this.baseArray = base;
  }

  // Getter
  public int get(int index) {
    return baseArray[2 * index + 1];  // Odd entries only.
  }

  // Setter
  public void set(int index, int value) {
    baseArray[2 * index + 1] = value;  // Odd entries only.
  }

  // Return changed baseArray.
  public int[] getBaseArray() {
    return baseArray;
  }

} // end class OddArray
```

That needs some error checking etc. added, but it hides all the even positions allowing you to treat the array as if only the odd positions existed and were numbered 0, 1, 2, ...  Once the array is sorted, call `OddArray.getBaseArray()` to retrieve the whole array.

Answer (score 2):

Another answer with streams:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class IntSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[]{5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4, 0};
        final int[] result = sortOnlyOddRemainEven(array);
    }

    public static int[] sortOnlyOddRemainEven(int[] array) {
        final LinkedList<Integer> collect;
        collect = Arrays.stream(array)
                        .filter(x -> x % 2 != 0)
                        .boxed()
                        .sorted()
                        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));

        return IntStream.of(array)
                        .map(value -> value % 2 != 0 ? collect.pop() : value)
                        .toArray();
    }
}
```